# Rock, Paper, Scissors code is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why my Rock, Paper, Scissors code is returning undefined when I run it. This is code that I've changed as initially, my code would return "You Win! undefined beats undefined" and I was unable to get the program to see the variables that I thought I had already initialized.

I've commented out the last else because I'm also having trouble understanding why my program ignores user input and just returns "It's a tie! Try again." I've tried to set the rules of the game in the if statement and avoid my strings being equal when comparing them but it doesn't seem to be working since the program is returning a tie? I've viewed so many other answers and solutions when trying to fix the code that I've now just confused myself. I'll attach the code below :

```js
const choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
const playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, Scissors?"); 
const computerSelection = computerPlay();

function caseInsensitive(playerSelection) {
    return playerSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + playerSelection.slice(1);
}

function computerPlay(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length);
    return choice[random];
};

function playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection) {
    
    if (playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        return (`You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`);
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        return (`You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`);
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        return (`You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`);  
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        return (`You Lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`);
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection =="Rock") {
        return (`You Lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`);
    }
    else if (playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        return (`You Lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`);
    }
   /* else {
        return (`It's a tie! Try again.`);
    } */
   };

console.log(playRound());
```

Comment: You need to pass the variables to `playRound` like `console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));`

Comment: You're not passing parameters `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` that the constructor of `playRound()` expects. So both variables are set to `undefined` and you have no condition in your code to handle that. Alternatively, remove it from the constructor if you want to use the globally declared variables of the same name.

Comment: @Adrian nitpick but its a method not a constructor!

Comment: Just remove the arguments of `playRound()`. It is creating a local variables fir `playerSelection`, and `computerSelection` which are `undeinfed` since you are not passing anything while calling the function. removing the args will fallback to global references of the    `playerSelection`, and `computerSelection` and the game should work

Comment: @Jamiec Absolutely right, sorry :)

Comment: Also you'll want to put back in your `else` case otherwise a tie will srtill log `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the values so that your function can return a string with those names which will be logged to console.

```js
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```